# How to make screen reader read the Live-region text first and input button label after

Tags: html, accessibility, screen-readers, jaws-screen-reader, aria-live

I've added a button which have aria-label attribute set and an event listener is added to that button.

```html
<button onClick: toggleFavourite(),
        aria-label = "favourite button label">
</button>
```

Now on JavaScript side, I've written code on toggleFavourite() method call where I'll create a <div> and append it to the body and for that div I've set the "aria-live" property to "Assertive". Below is the code for that.

```js
toggleFavourite(): void {
        var el = document.createElement("div");
        var id = "speak-" + Date.now();
        el.setAttribute("id", id);
        el.setAttribute("aria-live", "assertive");
        el.classList.add("visually-hidden");
        document.body.appendChild(el);
        var newelem = document.getElementById(id);
        setTimeout(() => {
            if (newelem != null) {
                newelem.innerHTML = "this label should be read first";
            }
        }, 100);

        setTimeout(() => {
            if (newelem != null) {
                document.body.removeChild(newelem);
            }
        }, 1000);
    }
```

Tried above solution but it was still reading the button label first and then the message defined in toggleFavourite() method. How to change this order i.e. read the message written in method first and label after?

Comment: Your question is a little unclear: do you mean the order of what's spoken when you click on the button ? IF yes, then you have no control on it. By the way, you see that assertive doesn't actually make your message more assertive; I recommend switching to polite .

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what your timing of interactions is. If you <kbd>tab</kbd> to the button, you should hear *"favourite button label, button"*.  Period. That's all you should hear.

After tabbing to the button, when you select it, new content is added.  That new content **might** be announced. Live regions that are dynamically added have spotty support with various browser and screen reader combinations. It's generally recommended that live regions exist on the page and then you add content **to** the live region.  [See one of my previous answers about live regions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75178816/nvda-chrome-reads-anchor-text-inside-a-hidden-div-twice-when-displayed/75189223#75189223).

> Tried above solution but it was still reading the button label first and then the message defined in toggleFavourite() method.

This is the confusing part of your question.  The button label and the newly added text are separate things. Why should they both be announced?